# Relationship between singularities and non-identifiability in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

What's a **singularity** in the context of **non-identifiability** of neural networks? For example, I read [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.09175):

> **Skip connections** made the training of very deep networks possible and have become an indispensable component in a variety of neural architectures. A completely satisfactory explanation for their success remains elusive. Here, we present a novel explanation for the benefits of skip connections in training very deep networks. **The difficulty of training deep networks is partly due to the singularities caused by the non-identifiability of the model**. Several such singularities have been identified in previous works: (i) overlap singularities caused by the permutation symmetry of nodes in a given layer, (ii) elimination singularities corresponding to the elimination, i.e. consistent deactivation, of nodes, (iii) singularities generated by the linear dependence of the nodes. These **singularities** cause **degenerate manifolds in the loss landscape** that slow down learning. We argue that skip connections eliminate these singularities by **breaking the permutation symmetry** of nodes, by reducing the possibility of node elimination and by making the nodes less linearly dependent.

The abstract assumes that there is a known connection between non-identifiability and singularities and they argue that skip connections help with this problem.

But I don't understand what they even mean by "singularity" here. Is a singularity a point where the gradient vanishes? Perhaps when the loss or the gradient is not defined? Or something else altogether?

Comment: The answer appears to be directly in the content of the abstract. "Several such singularities have been identified in previous works: (i) overlap singularities caused by the permutation symmetry of nodes in a given layer, (ii) elimination singularities corresponding to the elimination, i.e. consistent deactivation, of nodes, (iii) singularities generated by the linear dependence of the nodes." Can you elaborate on how this is not a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Thanks @Sycorax I updated the OP. My question is about what they mean by "singularity". My understanding is that a singularity is when a function or condition vanishes or when it becomes undefined. But if so, what's vanishing or becoming undefined? Given that they state that the connection between non-identifiability and singularities is well established, I assume that it has a standard meaning. Is it e.g. that the loss function is not defined? the gradient vanishes? Or are they using the term singularity more figuratively when something "undesirable" happens? (but if so what exactly?)